# MySqlConnector.Net slow on connection open

Tags: c#, mysql-connector, amazon-aurora

I'm using the MySqlConnector.Net package in my application to communicate with an AWS Aurora database, and the initial opening of the connection is slow. After the first conneciton, the rest of the calls are all using the pool as I'd expect and everything is very fast.

This is  a simplified example of my code, but on the first run, this little bit takes ~2 - 3 seconds to run. Subsequent calls are near instant as I'd expect. I've seen some articles here and there mentioning stuff about this issue, but I'm having trouble finding any fixes or answers.

```
var Con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString));            
if (Con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    Con.Open();
```

Comment: Post your (obfuscated) connection string.

Comment: @mxmissile `server=awsendpoint;uid=myuser;pwd=mypassword;database=dbo;`